# How to make calls to 2 APIs from one controller action in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a `ItemsController` with a `Get` action (`getItemSellers\{itemId}`) that will call a method in `ItemServices` (`GetSellers(itemId)`) and get a list of sellers selling a particular item from a third party API, which I parse and create a `Item` model. I want to call another API to get ratings for each seller and add it to my `Item model`. Ultimately, I am grabbing a bunch of information from one API and turning it into one model, then I want to update that model with information that I grab from another API. Anyone have an idea how to best accomplish this? I'm not saving anything into a database, just passing what my model looks like to the client.

Basically, after first API call:

```
{ 
   data: 
      { 
          itemId: 123, 
          sellers: [
              { 
                  seller1: abc 
              }, 
              { 
                  seller2: abc
              }
          ] 
      }
}
```

After second API call, and what I want to return to my controller:

```
{ 
   data: 
      { 
          itemId: 123, 
          sellers: [
              { 
                  seller1: abc,
                  rating: 5
              }, 
              { 
                  seller2: abc,
                  rating: 3
              }
          ] 
      }
}
```

Comment: How looks data received from second API?

Comment: Hi @Fabio, I have to send out separate calls to the second API for each individual seller with the seller information in a query, and then it returns something like { sellerName: name, lengthInBusiness: 365, ... userRatings: 5 }

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a SellerViewModel class to hold the additional information (or use the Model you have right now).
2. I recommend using JsonServiceClient (in ServiceStack.Client package) to deserialize the seller rating API you plan to call.

usage example (for each seller)

```
using(var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://api.seller-ratings.com")
{
    // assuming SellerRatingModel has SellerID and Rating properties
    var result = client.Get<SellerRatingModel>("/sellers/1");
    // Do assignment here
}
```

I should point out that http calls are expensive to do for each seller, and thus, you are better of passing a range of Seller IDs to the rating API and get all the information you need in one go. You can then do a linq join with the data you have from the first api. Of course, your ratings API needs to support this

```
using(var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://api.seller-ratings.com")
{
    // assuming SellerRatingModel has SellerID and Rating properties
    var result = client.Get<IEnumerable<SellerRatingModel>>("/sellers?Ids=1,2,3,4,5");
    // Do assignment here
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Eyassu! Do you suggest that I just chain this onto my `GetSellers(itemId)` after the first API call results in a success?

Comment: It depends on your API structure. Assuming you have this structure Item -> Sellers -> Rating, if the 3rd party API accepts Id Ranges for getting seller information, use it once inside GetSellers. I don't think you should ever get each seller's information one by one. That would be a chatty and expensive API design. 

You can also try to create a service that gets multiple seller information in parallel. and then return them using Task.WhenAll()